# How do I delete an instance of an intermediate model in a Django Many-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, instance

According to an [example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), I have three models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

Adding members works. But how do I delete a single Membership instance
(a User quits a group), without deleting neither the User, nor the Group?

When I try deleting it like this:

```
    u = User(request.user)
    g = Group.objects.get(id=group_id, membership__user=u)
    m = Membership(user=request.user, group=g)
    m.delete()
```

I get an error:

> AssertionError at /groups/quit/1/
>
> Membership object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to
>   None.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the line

```
m = Membership(user=request.user, group=g)
```

You created a new `Membership` you didn't fetch one from the database.  That is why its id attribute is set to None.

Perhaps you meant

```
m = Membership.objects.get(user=request.user, group=g)
```

Answer (score 4):

This particular error is triggered by the fact, that your `m` instance of class `Membership` is unsaved, so its primary key is None. Apparently, it is impossible to delete such an unsaved instance (which makes sense, because there is nothing to "delete").